# React Native Paper single date picker not showing save button

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, expo, react-native-paper

I'm creating an app with React Native Paper as my UI framework, and I'm trying to add a single date picker with React Native Paper Dates. The date picker works, but I can't see the save button that is supposed to be there. If I press in the right-hand corner where it is supposed to be, it works, but the button is invisible.

Can anyone please help me fix this problem?

This is my code:

```js
<View>
            <Text>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
            <TimePickerModal
              visible={visible && mode === 'time'}
              onDismiss={onDismiss}
              onConfirm={onConfirm}
            />

            <DatePickerModal
              locale="en-GB"
              mode="single"
              visible={visible && mode === 'date'}
              onDismiss={onDismiss}
              date={date}
              onConfirm={onConfirmSingle}
            />

            <View
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}
            >
              <Button
                mode="outlined"
                onPress={() => {
                  setMode('time')
                  setVisible(true)
                }}
                style={{ width: '50%' }}
              >
                Select Time
              </Button>
              <Button
                onPress={() => {
                  setMode('date')
                  setVisible(true)
                }}
                uppercase={false}
                mode="outlined"
                style={{ width: '50%' }}
              >
                Pick date
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
```

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: Image of how the date picker looks on my phone]

I thought maybe the color of the button was the problem, so I tried adding a color property to the styles of the date picker, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while working on my React Native app with React Native Paper for UI and React Native Paper Dates for the date picker. After some investigation, I found a solution that worked for me.

Firstly, I explored the sample code inside the Expo Snack, and everything was working perfectly there. It led me to believe that there might be a discrepancy in the dependencies between my project and the sample.

Here are the dependencies that worked for me, which I updated in my package.json:

> ```
> "react-native-paper": "5.0.2",
> "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.11.0"
> ```

After updating these dependencies, I ran `npm install` to ensure that the modules were updated accordingly. This resolved my issue with the invisible save button, and it became visible.